# 419 Page Expired in laravel 7

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-7

I have error *419 | Page Expired* when i login in my website, i alrady use **@csrf** in my form.
what can i do to fix this problem ?

> this is my login.php file

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')
<div class="container">
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
        <div class="col-md-8">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-header">{{ __('Login') }}</div>

                <div class="card-body">
                    <form method="POST" action="{{ route('login') }}">
                        @csrf

                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="email" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('E-Mail Address') }}</label>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input id="email" type="email" class="form-control @error('email') is-invalid @enderror" name="email" value="{{ old('email') }}" required autocomplete="email" autofocus>

                                @error('email')
                                    <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                        <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                @enderror
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="password" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('Password') }}</label>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input id="password" type="password" class="form-control @error('password') is-invalid @enderror" name="password" required autocomplete="current-password">

                                @error('password')
                                    <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                        <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                @enderror
                            </div>
                        </div>
```

[image: this is the screenshot Page Expired]

Comment: what does your laravel.log file say. Take a quick look on the error. And I am sure that you are closing the form. Please make sure you paste the complete code

Comment: try php artisan key:generate or clearing browser history or php artisan view:clear

Answer (score 0):

try **clearing the browser cache** as well as laravel with `php artisan cache:clear.`
Sometime 419 is due to stale cache.